# Why gcd(a,b) is the same as solving for gcd(b,a-b) in the Euclidean algorithm

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am a number theory hobbyist, and have recently started to read the book [Excursions in Number Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486257789). I am at a point where the author is trying to reason why Euclid's algorithm for finding the *gcd* of 2 numbers work. I am unable to get my head around the fact that *gcd(a,b)* is the same as solving for *gcd(b,a-b)*. Is there some way I can intuitively understand why this is so? I have gone through several explanations where they use modular arithmetic and Euclid's division algorithm to explain it and I am afraid I dont get it.

Comment: Consider the fraction $\dfrac86$. This fraction isn't reduced; the numerator and denominator need to be divided out by $2$. Now, subtract $1$, to get $\dfrac86-1=\dfrac26$. It's still not reduced; the numerator and denominator still need to be divided out by $2$. In other words, the gcd of the numerator and denominator _didn't change when I subtracted $1$ from the fraction_. Does this always happen?

Answer (score 0):

Enlarge the problem: what is actually true is that the set of common divisors $D(a,b)$ of $a$ and $b$ is the same as $D(b, a-b)$ – and also the same as $D(b,a\bmod b)$.

Indeed a number which divides both $a$ and $b$, also divides $a-b$: this proves $D(a,b)\subseteq D(b,a-b)$.

Conversely, a number which divides $b$ and $a-b$  also divides $b+(a-b)=a$, whence the reverse inclusion.